# How can I convert a classic .lvl file into a modern Minecraft format

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mcedit

I have tried opening .lvl with the latest version of MCEdit, and I get random stuff. No sense of order at all. I am not entirely surprised because it was not a supported extension in the Open dialog.

What program would you recommend to open [this file](http://www.minecraftworldmap.com/worlds/4NNed)?

Comment: I took a look at it in MCedit and saw the same thing. It's possible the file is simply corrupt.